# XLSXWriter formula across more than one column

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to apply a simple multiplication formula (B1=B2*B3...C1=C2*C3) for every column in a spreadsheet.

I've reviewed the (fantastic) xlsxwriter documentation, as well as this similar question: [XLSXWriter Apply Formula Across Column With Dynamic Cell Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944961/xlsxwriter-apply-formula-across-column-with-dynamic-cell-reference), but I can't get it to work across multiple columns.  Going down a single column is easy using a loop and incrementing the value of the row number, but I'm having trouble applying the same concept across a row (multiple columns).

I'm using `xl_rowcol_to_cell()` to get the A1 notation of the final cells in the spreadsheet (because it's going to be different every time), but I can't figure out how to plug those variables into a workable formula or array formula.

```
cell1 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(1, total_columns - 1)
cell2 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(2, total_columns - 1)
cell3 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(3, total_columns - 1)
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
worksheet.write_array_formula('B1:%s', '{=PRODUCT(B2:%s,B3:%s)}' % (cell1, cell2, cell3))
```

But I keep having problems with string formatting, and when I try just plugging in actual values instead of using string formatting I get garbage out of Excel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood how array formulas are used.  The question I linked had enough information to solve my problem:

```
for col_num in range(1, total_columns):
    worksheet.write_formula(1, col_num, '=B2:%s*B3:%s' % (cell2, cell3))
```